# Mangento 2 with Angular JS

Tags: magento2, angularjs

Nowadays everyone is talking about Magento 2 with Angular JS but I haven't found anything relevant to start with. Can someone please guide me that how and from where I can start the implementation of Magento2 with Angular JS?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing an MVC framework meant that rather than having the customer browse through different pages of the website, we will be making him browse through different views of the Angular template. This way the whole page would never be loaded every time the user navigates to an internal page. Instead, the focus would only be on sections of the template which keep on loading data in the background through web services.

To know more about the angularJS - https://www.softsuave.com/blog/trendy-about-angular-js-that-everyone-went-crazy-over-it/